# Resize to the photo.stackexchange.com header photo size with Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing, cropping

I want to submit a photo to photo.stackexchange.com site (like [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/488/weekly-featured-image-for-nov-29-2010)) and they ask for a specific maximum image size (375x210).

Is there an easy way to resize and crop an image to this size using Lightroom? Or do I have to use another program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this in two stages:

1. Crop to the correct aspect ratio (25:14)
2. Export to email, and change the dimensions to be 375px wide.